# resize image to fit browser window bigger than image width

Tags: javascript, css

i'm looking to resize my images in my image slider automatically to fit the browser window while keeping my image size as low as possible. The images itself have a fixed width of 800px but when the browser window scales to more than that the images don't scale along. They stay a fixed 800px. Is there a way to resolve that.

You can see an example at: http://www.continuous-ltd.be/ctb-site/indextest.html

thx

Comment: i think there might be something wrong with the example as well, only the first picture will scale.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `background-size: 100%;` but keep in mind that it's not implemented on all browsers yet

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
max-width:100%
```

Comment: it was really as simple as that? thanks, i was thinking too far!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this css

```
.slides, .slides li, .slides li img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```